# Cloudformation Error(Value of property Stepadjustments must be a list of objects)

Tags: json, ruby, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I keep getting this resource creation error when i try to launch the stack

```
    ServiceScalingPolicyIn:
    Properties:
      PolicyName: StepDown
      PolicyType: StepScaling
      ScalingTargetId:
        Ref: ServiceScalingTarget
      StepScalingPolicyConfiguration:
        AdjustmentType: ChangeInCapacity
        Cooldown: '300'
        MetricAggregationType: Average
        StepAdjustments:
        - - MetricIntervalLowerBound: '0'
            ScalingAdjustment:
              Ref: TasksCount
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy

CPUAlarmScalein:
    Properties:
      EvaluationPeriods: '1'
      Statistic: Average
      Threshold: '25'
      AlarmDescription: Alarm if CPU usage is lower, this will always be
      Period: '300'
      AlarmActions:
      - Ref: ServiceScalingPolicyIn
      Namespace: AWS/ECS
      Dimensions:
      - Name: ClusterName
        Value: ECS365-sandbox
      - Name: ServiceName
        Value: ECSService365
      ComparisonOperator: LessThanThreshold
      MetricName: CPUUtilization
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
```

I tried tweaking changes

```
ServiceScalingTarget:
DependsOn: ECSService365
Properties:
  MaxCapacity: '10'
  MinCapacity: '1'
  ResourceId:
    Fn::Join:
    - ''
    - - service/
      - Ref: Cluster365
      - "/"
      - Fn::GetAtt:
        - ECSService365
        - Name
  RoleARN:
    Fn::GetAtt:
    - AutoscalingRole
    - Arn
  ScalableDimension: ecs:service:DesiredCount
  ServiceNamespace: ecs
Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
```

full stack link https://github.com/manideep444/cloudformations/blob/master/365sandbox.yml
AWS Doc:
Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling originally supported only simple scaling policies. If you created your scaling policy before target tracking and step policies were introduced, your policy is treated as a simple scaling policy.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARKVE.png)

Comment: This is a bit unrelated to the question, but what are the benefits of using cfndsl over YAML templates? This makes debugging your particular problem harder as you added a moving part to the process.

Comment: updated to yaml

Comment: here is the full stack https://github.com/manideep444/cloudformations/blob/master/365sandbox.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"StepAdjustments" should be a [list](https://github.com/Animosity/CraftIRC/wiki/Complete-idiot%27s-introduction-to-yaml#lists), not a list inside a list.

Here is an example from the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-policy.html).

```
StepAdjustments: 
      - 
        MetricIntervalLowerBound: "0"
        MetricIntervalUpperBound: "50"
        ScalingAdjustment: "1"
      - 
        MetricIntervalLowerBound: "50"
        ScalingAdjustment: "2"
```

Comment: the error is similar to that thanks, i use cfndsl to convert ruby to json and then to yaml for simplicity. replaced "square bracket" with "bracket" in my ruby template..did the trick